# i can't get data from one of my forms

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.6

I create a page with two form i want to get data of each form when the button is submitted, the probleme here is i can get data just for one of the form

this is my indexAction :

```
    public function indexCcpAction ()
{

    $demanceCCP = new DemandeCCP();
    $ccp = new Ccp();
    $formDemanceCCP = $this->createForm(new DemandeCcpType(), $demanceCCP);
    $formCcp = $this->createForm(new LoginCcpType(), $ccp);
    $formCcp->handleRequest($this->get('request'));
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    if ( $this->get("request")->getMethod() == "POST" ) {
            if ($this->get("request")->request->has("DemandeCcpType")  ) {
                $demanceCCP = $formDemanceCCP->getData(); // i can't get data from this form
                echo($demanceCCP->getNom());
                $em->persist($demanceCCP);
                $em->flush();
            }
            if ($this->get("request")->request->has("LoginCcpType")) {
                $ccp = $formCcp->getData(); // but in this form work
                echo ($ccp->getMdp());
            }
    }
    return $this->render('EgovPosteBundle:Ccp:DemanceCCP.html.twig',
        array('formDemandeCcp'=>$formDemanceCCP->createView(),
              'formLogin'=>$formCcp->createView()));
}
```

I get this exception when i try to insert data of the DemandeCcpType

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO DemandeCCP (nom,
>   prenom, dateNaissance, lieuNaissance, profession, nationalite,
>   typePieceIdentite, numeroIdentite, adresse, email, tel, codePostal,
>   sollicite, dateDemancde, statut) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
>   null, null, null, null, null, null, "2016-05-11 03:25:36", "en cour"]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'nom'
>   cannot be null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only called handleRequest for one of your forms. It needs to be called for both.

Add `$formDemanceCCP->handleRequest($this->get('request'));`